# ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save() in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to generate uuid into database as primary key. I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_keys
(
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
    ....
}
```

I tried to insert new key using this Java code:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductKeysRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductKeys, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ProductKeys> {

    ......
}

ProductKeys productKeys= ProductKeys.builder().build();
productKeysRepository.saveAndFlush(productKeys);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_keys")
public class ProductKeys{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    ....
}
```

When I try to insert a new record I get a error: `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.ProductKeys`

I don't have a sequencer. I want to leave database to generate the unique uuid. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add the id as a UUID and auto generated one, you can use the annotation to do that. then you don't  want to provide the id each time. the id will be generated by the framework.

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
```

or, if the Id generating is required by the Database, **you have to manage another column as a primary key in the database besides the main primary key**. because JPA requires that every entity has an ID.